# simple php script not working

Tags: php, http, parsing, post

I'm working on a project in which I need to send data to my webpage via an HTTP POST request from my Android phone.

The PHP code that I'm working on is the following :

```
<?php    
echo "<pre>"    
print_r($_POST);    
?>
```

When I try to open that script (i.e., go to www.mywebpage/script.php on my phone's browser) I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' 
in /home/smartpho/public_html/phpskripta/script.php on line 3
```

I don't understand why this is happening, since I *do* have a ';' on line 3.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on line 2. The error message is simply telling you that line 3 is where the error was first noticed by the parser.

Answer (score 8):

You forgot a semicolon after `echo "<pre>"`.

Here's the correct code (both correct PHP syntax and less-invalid HTML):

```
<?php    
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);    
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Btw, the error message told you exactly the correct information: You just need a semicolon before something else occurs. So the parser detects the error in line 3 as it doesn't expect `print_r` right after a string. For example, the following would be correct, too (but obviously horrible to read):

```
echo 'meow'
;print_r($_POST)
;
```

Comment: The error is gone, now I get some japanese letters : 戼⁲㸯㰊㹢慆慴⁬牥潲㱲戯㨾†慃汬琠⁯湵敤楦敮⁤畦据楴湯†⡰ 湩㰠㹢栯浯⽥浳牡灴潨瀯扵楬彣瑨汭瀯灨歳楲瑰⽡捳楲瑰瀮灨⼼㹢漠⁮楬敮㰠㹢㰳戯㰾牢⼠ਾ